Text widget scroll is not working within Frame
This is very strange and I wonder if there's any fix besides "add extra space at the bottom"
Here's some sample code to explain what I'm doing:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x300")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

box = Text(root, wrap="char", cursor="arrow", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 30))
box.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.config( command = box.yview )
scrollbar.lift()

for i in range(5):
    box.insert(INSERT, f"Button {i+1} ")

root.mainloop()

This works amazing and this is what the max scroll looks like:

However, once I put everything in a Frame there's a problem
Code:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x400")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(x=0, y=100, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

box = Text(frame, wrap="char", cursor="arrow", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 30))
box.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.config( command = box.yview )
scrollbar.lift()

for i in range(5):
    box.insert(INSERT, f"Button {i+1} ")

root.mainloop()

And the max scroll looks like this:

As you can see, at least 2 lines in the text widget were cutoff, and I have no idea why. Can someone help out?

Part of the frame is out of viewable area of the window, so that of the text and scrollbar widgets.  I wonder why you put the frame at y=100.

for Frame you use place() and for Scrollbar you use pack() and this can makes difference.

@acw1668 Above that I was going to put another frame for other widgets, such as buttons. So I left some space at the top for them

@furas How exactly? I packed the scrollbar to make it stick to the right and fill the Y, neither place nor grid could help me do that. I found that by default it sticked to the west or left.

first you put Scroll and Text with pack() directly in window - so it automatically resize/crop Scroll and Text to windows size, but later you put it in Frame which uses place() - and you add y=100 - and place doesn't crop it to windows size - so some part of Frame is below window border and you don't see full content. If Frame would use pack() then it could crop Frame to windows height.

This is because of the incorrect geometry settings for the root window and the frame widget.
Example -1:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Set a more appropriate geometry
root.geometry("600x400")  

# Use the entire root window
frame = Frame(root)
frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)  

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

box = Text(frame, wrap="char", cursor="arrow", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 30))
box.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.config(command=box.yview)

for i in range(5):
    box.insert(INSERT, f"Button {i+1} ")

root.mainloop()

You  may think what to do if you want to display another widget above the frame. The solution is to use pack or grid to properly allocate space. The following example with grid but still make your Text widget scrollable.
Example-2
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")

# Adding another widget at the top
top_label = Label(root, text="This is the top label", font=("Helvetica", 16))
top_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")  # Adjust to fill remaining space

scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

box = Text(frame, wrap="char", cursor="arrow", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, font=("Helvetica", 30))
box.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
scrollbar.config(command=box.yview)

# Configure the grid to expand properly
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

for i in range(50):  # Add more lines to test scrolling
    box.insert(INSERT, f"Button {i+1} ")

root.mainloop()

I've given the above examples so that one can compare and understand the concept.
Edit for more clarity:
Whether you use grid or pack, Have an approximate idea of how much space each widget will occupy and what  is the height  and breadth of the root window. Let us assume the first 4 widgets occupy 380px vertically and the height of your root window is 400. So only 20px is remaining. If the height of your 5th widget is more than 20px, The excess height will be clipped even though if you had given scroll bar.

I looked at it again and it seems that Example-2 does address my problem, thank you

Knowing that you might of put another widget on the top, I've given 2nd example.  Whether you use grid or pack, Have an approximate idea of how much space each widget will occupies and what  is the height  and breadth of the root window. Let us assume the first 4 widgets occupy 380px vertically and the height of your root window is 400. So only 20px is remaining. If the height of your 5th widget is more than 20px, The excess height will be clipped even though if you had given scroll bar.
